# Can I access call transcripts for voice contacts programmatically in Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ivr, amazon-connect

I am working on a customer service application that integrates the Amazon Connect Customer Control Panel to handle answering customer calls while looking up customer data from DynamoDB and Salesforce, using a pattern much like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/building-a-survey-ivr-system-with-amazon-connect/) (but without connecting to Kinesis). We are using [this library](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams) on the front end to integrate with Connect.

One of the features we want to add is viewing call transcripts within our application. The [Connect documentation about recording behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/set-up-recordings.html) states that recordings (and sentiment analysis) are stored in S3, so we don't have any problem with getting access to call recordings in our application. When looking at that S3 bucket, there aren't any transcripts included, only a WAV file for the recording and a JSON file for the sentiment analysis. Transcripts are available in that bucket for chat contacts, but not voice contacts as far as I can tell.

I can see the call transcript in the Connect console, but we have a specific ask to make the transcript available in our application without users needing to go to the Connect console. From [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/view-call-transcript-ccp.html) and [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/turn-by-turn-transcript.html)  I am only seeing the option to view the transcript from the Connect console. Since they are available there I'm sure the transcript is stored somewhere, I just don't know if Connect makes that available to developers directly in the same way it does with voice contact recordings or chat contact transcripts.

**Is it possible to access the transcripts for voice contacts directly rather than downloading them from the Connect console?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think it’s possible. It might be that AWS wants you to use Amazon Transcribe https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/